# onclick event not firing or not being subscribed to with buttons in a loop

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm trying to get an array of button's click events subscribed to and then to redirect by pulling the location from an attribute. I had trouble getting this to work and now it has boiled down to the following...

```
function pushButton() {
    window.alert('Hello World');
}

var listButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for (var i = 0; i < listButtons.length; i++) {
    listButtons[i].addEventListener('click', pushButton, false);
}
```

This is in script tags at the bottom of page (after the buttons have been declared).

I've also tried...

```
...
for (var i = 0; i < listButtons.length; i++)
    listButtons[i].onclick = function(i) {
        return function() {
            alert('Hello World');
        }
    }(i);
}
```

and...

```
...
(function(i) {
    listButtons[i].onclick = (function() {
        window.alert('Hello World');
})})(i);
```

based on other examples I've seen around. The problem is that nothing happens when a button is clicked on. I've used developer view in Chrome to look for errors but it hasn't shown any. I've also tried in Firefox and IE to no avail.

I did have a couple of examples that would fire all the events using `onclick` and I get that it is due to the event firing when being subscribed to. But even after that, the button doesn't do anything. I was using `onclick` but now I've moved to `addEventListener` which doesn't have a different result.

I'm trying to avoid jQuery and just use vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Have you attempted to inspect the value of `listButtons` after it is initialized and verified that it includes the elements you expect?

Comment: @Gian - Yeah I have and I'm getting back all the items ok. The count is also correct. There's about 18 buttons at the moment.

Comment: Your minimal example works as expected for me.  I would next attempt to verify that the listener is actually attached to the button (using the Chrome developer pane).

Comment: @Gian - Looking for the event listener is what tipped me off to the real cause as I've posted. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In attempt to remove all possible causes, I started to strip out all javascript functions and events to narrow things down.

It turns out the issue was being caused by an function being called in the body onload event. This function changes the position of the buttons by manipulating the innerHTML of the containing div. When the innerHTML was rewritten, it destroys all the event listeners.

This caused no event listeners and no errors symptoms that was being seen. The original code worked fine once the onload event was modified to add the event listeners again.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your first code example and got it to work like this:

```
function pushButton() {
    alert('Hello World');
}

listButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')

for (var i = 0; i < listButtons.length; i++) {
    listButtons[i].addEventListener('click', pushButton);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The cause was in some code that I hadn't written as per my answer. Thanks for helping feel less crazy about what I'd written though.

Answer (score 1):

your code work fine on my computer, fllow is my code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="btn1"></input> 
        <form>
            <input type="text"></input> 
            <input type="text"></input> 
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="btn2"></input> 
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="btn3"></input> 
       </form>  
      </div>
    </body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function pushButton() {
            window.alert('Hello World');
        }

        var listButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

        for (var i = 0; i < listButtons.length; i++) {
            listButtons[i].addEventListener('click', pushButton, false);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: The cause was in another piece of code that was being executed after this snippet. Thanks for taking the time to prove my code should have been working.

Answer (score 0):

If you included the JavaScript before the body (in the head) it won't work. the binding is happening before the DOM is ready.

If you put the JavaScript at the bottom of the page just before  it will work.

Another work around this is using jQuery document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click',function(){
        alert('Hellow World');
    });

});
```

Comment: As per my question, the code was in the body and I wanted to avoid jQuery. Thanks though.